# GoCD - Notification for GoAgent status changes(missing/lost contact)

Tags: continuous-deployment, go-cd, thoughtworks-go, go-server, go-agent

I am using `GoCD` for the automated deployment of our application. I am facing an `serious issue`, that is if any agent `lost contact/missing` - its corresponding `pipeline` just `hangs`.

There is no notification sent about the unavailability of the agent or pipeline is not getting failed.

Can anyone suggest if there is anyway to fix this issue with `GoCD` or any `plugins` that can be used to get notifications on `GoAgent` machine status?